# Having an issue with Javascript getElementsByTagName on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome, web

I am having an issue with getting xml tag name length in chrome browser. When I try this `getElementsByTagName("auth:accountInfo")` it is working fine on FF but not working on chrome. If I use `getElementsByTagName("accountInfo")` it is working on chrome but it is not working on FF. Can some one help me in writing correct logic which works on both browsers? Below is my sample code.

```
objXHR = XMLHttpRequest()
if(objXHR.status == 200)
        {
            var accountInfo = objXHR.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("auth:accountInfo");
            if (accountInfo.length > 0)
            {
                // do something
                }
```

Comment: This seems to be related to the namespace component, have you considered using [*XPath*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) instead?

Comment: Thank you Kaiido, torazaburo and RobG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagNameNS).

```js
getElementsByTagNameNS(authNS, 'accountInfo');
```

`authNS`, being the namespaceURI you've declared with the name `auth` in your XML doc.

Note that you could achieve the same with [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) query `//auth:accountInfo`, but you would need to pass an [`namespaceResolver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) function to return the correct nameSpaceURI. Also note that this method implies more code, and is slower than other DOM methods.

Finally, you could also achieve this with `querySelectorAll('*|accountInfo')`, but in this case, all elements with the tagName `accountInfo` would be picked, whatever their nameSpace.

```js
let start = _ =>{
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(sonnet, 'application/xml');
console.log('getElementsByTagNameNS');
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.authors.com/", 'author')[0].outerHTML);

// Alternatively with XPath
function resolveNS(name) {
  if (name === 'auth') {
    return 'http://www.authors.com/'
  }
}
var query = doc.evaluate("//auth:author", doc, resolveNS, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var elements = [];
var el;
while (el = query.iterateNext()) {
  elements.push(el);
}
console.log('XPATH');
console.log(elements[0].outerHTML)

// Or, with querySelectorAll
console.log('querySelectorAll');
console.log(doc.querySelectorAll('*|author')[0].outerHTML);
};

var sonnet = `<sonnet type='Shakespearean'>
  <auth:author xmlns:auth="http://www.authors.com/">
    <last-name>Shakespeare</last-name>
    <first-name>William</first-name>
    <nationality>British</nationality>
    <year-of-birth>1564</year-of-birth>
    <year-of-death>1616</year-of-death>
  </auth:author>
  <!-- Is there an official title for this sonnet? They're sometimes named after the first line. -->
  <title>Sonnet 130</title>
  <lines>
    <line>My mistress' eyes are nothing like the sun,</line>
    <line>Coral is far more red than her lips red.</line>
    <line>If snow be white, why then her breasts are dun,</line>
    <line>If hairs be wires, black wires grow on her head.</line>
    <line>I have seen roses damasked, red and white,</line>
    <line>But no such roses see I in her cheeks.</line>
    <line>And in some perfumes is there more delight</line>
    <line>Than in the breath that from my ...</line>
  </lines>
</sonnet>`;

start();
```